# Changing SIP to Numeric Mode

Tags: windows-mobile

I have a Windows Mobile Desktop Application that have some text fields which will only accept numeric values. I need to activate the number keys on the phone when those text boxes has the focus.

I'm not being able to find any solution on that. Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Moth has an example of switching the SIP to numeric mode (in C#, you didn't note your language choice) [on his blog](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/show-numeric-sip-for-wince-devices.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this

```
InputModeEditor.SetInputMode(textBox, InputMode.Numeric);
```

Comment: Can u pls explain where should i put this one. I tried that in textBox1_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) but didn't work.

Comment: After the initialization of the controls. Also it will only work on windows mobile std

InputModeEditor.SetInputMode(textBox1, InputMode.Numeric);